# Why does my banana chili start to wilt and seem to die off when it reaches 500 mm high?

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, chili

You can see the problem in the picture! I've grown chilies here for 25 years without problems.

[image]

Comment: The fact that they've gotten to this size makes me think it's pests, unless you've got a lot or rain recently. Check carefully along the stems and leaf undersides, and in the top layer of soil around the plant. If you find anything suspicious, report back.

Comment: I see this all the time with my chilis and they get past it. This happens mainly on hot dry days but it seems to be temporary.  Are you watering enough?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "unclear what you're asking." As far as I can tell, Grozdon has not returned to the site in quite some time. Therefore, it's likely that any further requests we make, such as adding pictures, details, or an update on how the plant is faring, will go unanswered. There are no answers, and the most recent comment is a number of months old. For those reasons, I think it makes sense to close the question.